# Neo4j/Cypher effective pagination with order by over large sub-graph

Tags: neo4j, pagination, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I have following simple relationship between `(:User)` nodes.

`(:User)-[:FOLLOWS {timestamp}]->(:User)`

If I paginate followers ordered by `FOLLOWS.timestamp` I'm running into performance problems when someone has millions of followers.

```
MATCH (u:User {Id:{id}})<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(follower)
WHERE f.timestamp <= {timestamp}
RETURN follower
ORDER BY f.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 100
```

What is suggested approach for paginating big sets of data when ordering is required?

**UPDATE**

```
follower             timestamp
---------------------------------------
id(1000000)          1455967905
id(999999)           1455967875
id(999998)           1455967234
id(999997)           1455967123
id(999996)           1455965321
id(999995)           1455964123
id(999994)           1455963645
id(999993)           1455963512
id(999992)           1455961343
....
id(2)                1455909382
id(1)                1455908432
```

I want to slice this list down using timestamp which set on `:FOLLOWS` relationship. If I want to return batches of 4 followers I take current timestamp first and return 4 most recent, then 1455967123 and 4 most recent and so on. In order to do this the whole list should be order by timestamp which results in performance issues on millions of records.

Comment: So you want to find the oldest followers?

Comment: Timestamps are monotonically increasing and new FOLLOWS relationships are inserted first, so if you want to find the most recent followers it should be really fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the most recent followers, i.e. where the timestamp is greater than a given time, it only has to traverse the most recent ones.

You can do it with (2) in **20ms**

If you are really looking for the oldest (first) followers it makes sense to skip ahead and don't look at the timestamp of every of the million followers (which takes about 1s on my system, see (3)). If you skip ahead the time goes down to **230ms**, see (1)

In general we can see that on my laptop it does 2M db-operations per core and second.

#### (1) Look at first / oldest followers

```
PROFILE
> MATCH (u)<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(follower) WHERE id(u) = 0
> // skip ahead
> WITH f,follower SKIP 999000
> // do the actual check
> WITH f,follower WHERE f.ts < 500
> RETURN f, follower
> ORDER BY f.ts
> LIMIT 10;
+---------------------------------+
| f                  | follower   |
+---------------------------------+
| :FOLLOWS[0]{ts:1}  | Node[1]{}  |
...
+---------------------------------+
10 rows
243 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.3 Planner COST Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Operator        | Estimated Rows | Rows    | DB Hits | Identifiers                                                             | Other                                 |
+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults |              1 |      10 |       0 | f, follower                                                             | f, follower                           |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Projection     |              1 |      10 |       0 | anon[142], anon[155], anon[158], anon[178], f, follower, f, follower, u | anon[155]; anon[158]                  |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Top            |              1 |      10 |       0 | anon[142], anon[155], anon[158], anon[178], f, follower, u              | Literal(10);                          |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Projection     |              1 |     499 |     499 | anon[142], anon[155], anon[158], anon[178], f, follower, u              | anon[155]; anon[158]; anon[155].ts    |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Projection     |              1 |     499 |       0 | anon[142], anon[155], anon[158], f, follower, u                         | f; follower                           |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |              1 |     499 |       0 | anon[142], f, follower, u                                               | anon[142]                             |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Projection     |              1 |    1000 |    1000 | anon[142], f, follower, u                                               | f; follower; f.ts < {  AUTOINT2}      |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Skip           |              1 |    1000 |       0 | f, follower, u                                                          | {  AUTOINT1}                          |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |              1 | 1000000 | 1000001 | f, follower, u                                                          | (u)<-[  f@12:FOLLOWS]-(  follower@24) |
| |               +----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| +NodeByIdSeek   |              1 |       1 |       1 | u                                                                       |                                       |
+-----------------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 1001501
```

#### (2) Look at most recent followers

```
PROFILE
> MATCH (u)<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(follower) WHERE id(u) = 0
> AND f.ts > 999500
> RETURN f, follower
> LIMIT 10;
+----------------------------------------------+
| f                           | follower       |
+----------------------------------------------+
| :FOLLOWS[999839]{ts:999840} | Node[999840]{} |
...
+----------------------------------------------+
10 rows
23 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.3 Planner COST Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator        | Estimated Rows | Rows  | DB Hits | Identifiers    | Other                                                         |
+-----------------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults |              1 |    10 |       0 | f, follower    | f, follower                                                   |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Limit          |              1 |    10 |       0 | f, follower, u | Literal(10)                                                   |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |              1 |    10 |   16394 | f, follower, u | AndedPropertyComparablePredicates(f,f.ts,f.ts > {  AUTOINT1}) |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |              1 | 16394 |   16395 | f, follower, u | (u)<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(follower)                                   |
| |               +----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByIdSeek   |              1 |     1 |       1 | u              |                                                               |
+-----------------+----------------+-------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 32790
```

#### (3) Find oldest followers without skipping ahead

```
PROFILE
> MATCH (u)<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(follower) WHERE id(u) = 0
> AND f.ts < 500
> RETURN f, follower
> LIMIT 10;
+-------------------------------------+
| f                     | follower    |
+-------------------------------------+
...
| :FOLLOWS[491]{ts:492} | Node[492]{} |
+-------------------------------------+
10 rows
1008 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.3 Planner COST Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator        | Estimated Rows | Rows   | DB Hits | Identifiers    | Other                                                         |
+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults |              1 |     10 |       0 | f, follower    | f, follower                                                   |
| |               +----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Limit          |              1 |     10 |       0 | f, follower, u | Literal(10)                                                   |
| |               +----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter         |              1 |     10 |  999498 | f, follower, u | AndedPropertyComparablePredicates(f,f.ts,f.ts < {  AUTOINT1}) |
| |               +----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +Expand(All)    |              1 | 999498 |  999499 | f, follower, u | (u)<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(follower)                                   |
| |               +----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| +NodeByIdSeek   |              1 |      1 |       1 | u              |                                                               |
+-----------------+----------------+--------+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 1998998
```

Comment: I'm looking into paginating using timestamp or most recent for given timestamp. So for the first page you will use current timestamp and so on. you basically slice from top to down in which case on ORDER BY you operating over the whole set of relationships. See my update.

Comment: Sure but you benefit from that followship is added in linear order, i.e more recent followers are added last and in neo4j's rel-chain they end up at the beginning of the chain. So when querying for most recent X you don't have to go further or even sort the million entries

Comment: So effectively you can amend ORDER BY clause if you need most recent on top. Still SKIP case won't work in pagination scenario as you need to know how many records to skip beforehand as new records can be inserted on top. Unless you somehow calculate initial offset. Plus if you need your list ordered by oldest first then you have to order.

Comment: Yes sure, but then showing oldest first is uncommon and if it is a **frequent requirement** then a modeling structure change would make more sense, e.g. by adding time-information to the rel-type (e.g month-year). After all reading and processing 1M records takes a bit.

Comment: what about range indexes?

Comment: I did a few tests around querying most recent followers and found that If I'm concurrently creating `:FOLLOW` relationships I can end up with relationships returned not in monotonic order which brings me back to using explicit `ORDER BY` by timestamp which has worst case performance. @michael-hunger could you advise.